# How can I select rows from one mysql table based on the row being timestamped after a date in another table

Tags: mysql

My problem downsized to the core part of it, how to show a merged output based on tables date entry.

It's really something else than temperature (and millions of lines) but I made up some numbers here just to illustrate the issue. I have several sensors, each sensor has an id number, each sensor sends out value information at somewhat random intervals. The sensors can move around so I have a separate table (SensorDescriptions) to keep track of when a sensor is moved. Each line there say when a sensor has moved and up until that point it must be considered to be in it's old location (and first entry in SensorDescriptions must be before first recorded value for that sensor).

The desired output is a list of time, sensor-name and value, I entered it in the DesiredOutput table but that is handcrafted (reservation for typos) - I need the query that produce it, "SELECT ... WHERE sv_date BETWEEN $startDate  AND $endDate".

Below is a text version of two sample tables (all hand crafted "random" values) and the output (saved a mysqldump at https://pastebin.com/88G77KiM).

So, what do I write that makes my mysql/mariadb SQL query merge SensorValues and SensorDescriptions so the output is like DesiredOutput?

SensorValues

```
+---------------------+-------+----------+
| sv_date             | sv_id | sv_value |
+---------------------+-------+----------+
| 2017-01-01 10:00:00 |     1 |       24 |
| 2017-01-01 10:01:00 |     2 |       13 |
| 2017-01-01 10:05:00 |     1 |     24.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:05:00 |     2 |     13.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:10:00 |     1 |     24.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:11:00 |     2 |     13.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:12:00 |     2 |     13.3 |
| 2017-01-01 10:15:00 |     1 |     24.3 |
| 2017-01-01 10:17:00 |     2 |     13.4 |
| 2017-01-01 10:20:00 |     1 |     24.4 |
| 2017-01-01 10:23:00 |     2 |       -5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:25:00 |     1 |     24.5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:30:00 |     1 |     24.6 |
| 2017-01-01 10:33:00 |     2 |     -5.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:35:00 |     1 |     -4.7 |
| 2017-01-01 10:37:00 |     2 |     -5.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:38:00 |     2 |     -5.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:40:00 |     1 |     -4.8 |
| 2017-01-01 10:41:07 |     1 |     -3.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:41:07 |     2 |     15.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:45:00 |     1 |     -4.9 |
| 2017-01-01 10:50:00 |     1 |       -5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:50:00 |     2 |       20 |
| 2017-01-01 10:51:00 |     2 |     20.1 |
+---------------------+-------+----------+
```

SensorDescriptions

```
+-------+---------------------+----------------+
| sv_id | sd_date             | sd_description |
+-------+---------------------+----------------+
|     1 | 2017-01-01 09:00:00 | Kitchen        |
|     1 | 2017-01-01 10:32:00 | Garage         |
|     2 | 2017-01-01 09:00:00 | Garage         |
|     2 | 2017-01-01 10:20:00 | Outside        |
|     2 | 2017-01-01 10:40:00 | Basement       |
+-------+---------------------+----------------+
```

DesiredOutput

```
+---------------------+----------+-------+
| sv_date             | Location | Value |
+---------------------+----------+-------+
| 2017-01-01 10:00:00 | Kitchen  |    24 |
| 2017-01-01 10:01:00 | Garage   |    13 |
| 2017-01-01 10:05:00 | Garage   |  13.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:05:00 | Kitchen  |  24.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:10:00 | Kitchen  |  24.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:11:00 | Garage   |  13.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:12:00 | Garage   |  13.3 |
| 2017-01-01 10:15:00 | Kitchen  |  24.3 |
| 2017-01-01 10:17:00 | Garage   |  13.4 |
| 2017-01-01 10:20:00 | Kitchen  |  24.4 |
| 2017-01-01 10:23:00 | Outside  |    -5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:25:00 | Kitchen  |  24.5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:30:00 | Kitchen  |  24.6 |
| 2017-01-01 10:33:00 | Outside  |  -5.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:35:00 | Garage   |  -4.7 |
| 2017-01-01 10:37:00 | Outside  |  -5.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:38:00 | Outside  |  -5.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:40:00 | Garage   |  -4.8 |
| 2017-01-01 10:41:07 | Basement |  15.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:41:07 | Garage   |  -3.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:45:00 | Garage   |  -4.9 |
| 2017-01-01 10:50:00 | Basement |    20 |
| 2017-01-01 10:50:00 | Garage   |    -5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:51:00 | Basement |  20.1 |
+---------------------+----------+-------+
```

---Edit---

I tried the one answer given but end up with errors but after having phpMyAdmin reformatting it I found the typo and got it to work, thanks.

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->     sv_date,
    ->     sd_description AS location,
    ->     sv_value
    -> FROM
    ->     SensorValues sv
    -> INNER JOIN
    ->     (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         sd1.sv_id,
    ->         sd1.sd_date,
    ->         sd1.sd_description,
    ->         COALESCE(
    ->             MIN(sd2.sd_date),
    ->             '9999-12-31 23:59:59'
    ->         ) AS next_sd_date
    ->     FROM
    ->         SensorDescriptions sd1
    ->     LEFT JOIN
    ->         SensorDescriptions sd2
    ->     ON
    ->         sd1.sv_id = sd2.sv_id AND sd1.sd_date < sd2.sd_date
    ->     GROUP BY
    ->         sd1.sv_id,
    ->         sd1.sd_date,
    ->         sd1.sd_description
    -> ) t
    -> ON
    ->     sv.sv_id = t.sv_id AND sv.sv_date >= t.sd_date AND sv.sv_date < t.next_sd_date;
+---------------------+----------+----------+
| sv_date             | location | sv_value |
+---------------------+----------+----------+
| 2017-01-01 10:00:00 | Kitchen  |       24 |
| 2017-01-01 10:05:00 | Kitchen  |     24.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:10:00 | Kitchen  |     24.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:15:00 | Kitchen  |     24.3 |
| 2017-01-01 10:20:00 | Kitchen  |     24.4 |
| 2017-01-01 10:25:00 | Kitchen  |     24.5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:30:00 | Kitchen  |     24.6 |
| 2017-01-01 10:35:00 | Garage   |     -4.7 |
| 2017-01-01 10:40:00 | Garage   |     -4.8 |
| 2017-01-01 10:41:07 | Garage   |     -3.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:45:00 | Garage   |     -4.9 |
| 2017-01-01 10:50:00 | Garage   |       -5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:01:00 | Garage   |       13 |
| 2017-01-01 10:05:00 | Garage   |     13.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:11:00 | Garage   |     13.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:12:00 | Garage   |     13.3 |
| 2017-01-01 10:17:00 | Garage   |     13.4 |
| 2017-01-01 10:23:00 | Outside  |       -5 |
| 2017-01-01 10:33:00 | Outside  |     -5.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:37:00 | Outside  |     -5.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:38:00 | Outside  |     -5.2 |
| 2017-01-01 10:41:07 | Basement |     15.1 |
| 2017-01-01 10:50:00 | Basement |       20 |
| 2017-01-01 10:51:00 | Basement |     20.1 |
+---------------------+----------+----------+
24 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each record in `SensorDescriptions` table I would get the timestamp of the next location (id any), which would provide the interval that can be used for joining that table to `SensorValues` table:

```
select sv_date, sd_description as location, sv_value
from SensorValues sv
inner join
    (select sd1.sv_id,
           sd1.sd_date,
           sd1.sd_description,
           coalesce(min(sd2.sd_date),'9999-12-31 23:59:59') as next_sd_date
    from SensorDescriptions sd1
    left join SensorDescriptions sd2 on sd1.sv_id=sd2.sv_id and sd1.sd_date<sd2.sd_date
    group by sd1.sv_id, sd1.sd_date, sd1.sd_description) t on sv.sv_id=t.sd_id and sv.sv_date>=t.sd_date and sv.sv_date<t.next_sd_date
```

Comment: Thanks for this, have to look at this closer so I understand what's going on but for a start I can't run the query as is on my MariaDB (10.1.21), I get
   ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'sv1.sd_date' in 'on clause'

Comment: That's because of a typo

Comment: Sorry, I have tried a few combinations but can't get it to work. Any hint on what the typo is ?

Comment: Come on, is there an sv1 alias in the query?

Comment: Well, the error I posted may been from my typo but I can't get it to work as is and while I did change around things nothing worked. Your exact code gives
MariaDB [test]> select sv_date, sd_description as location, sv_value
...
    ->     group by sd1.sv_id, sd1.sd_date, sd1.sd_description) t on sv.sv_id=t.sd_id and sv.sv_date>=t.sd_date and sv.sv_date<t.next_sd_date;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.sd_id' in 'on clause'
MariaDB [test]>

Comment: That's still because of a typo